# Cannot convert method group to non delegate type System.Data.Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, mvp

Cannot convert method group to non delegate type System.Data.Datatable. Did you intend to invoke the method? i'm using design pattern MVP (Model View Presenter)

So i have a DataTable in my Model

```
   DataTable _GetPendingTestOrders24Hours()
    {
        var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"];
        {
            string CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(CN);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter data = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            data.Fill(_dt);
            return _dt;
        }
    }
```

and a get and setter to pass the parameters to my Controller

```
 public DataTable GetPendingTestOrders24Hours
    {
        get { return _GetPendingTestOrders24Hours; }
        set
        {
            _GetPendingTestOrders24Hours = value;
        }
    }
```

but i'm getting the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently attempting to return a method group, as `_GetPendingTestOrders24Hours` is a method.

If you want to return the `DataTable`, you need to invoke the method:

```
public DataTable GetPendingTestOrders
{
    get { return GetPendingTestOrders24Hours(); }
}
```

As a side note, if you already have a method which queries the database, perhaps setting a read only property which simply invokes it might be redundant.

Also, note you should follow [C# naming coventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A method shouldn't start with a `_`.

Comment: oh my bad, i don't need a setter right? since i'm just reading the values.

Comment: A setter wouldn't make any sense in your case.